# Mostrar datos jquery en html

Tags: html, ajax, api, rest

La verdad me da un poco de vergüenza... por que no tengo ni idea solo tengo curiosidad y sigo tutoriales... jejejeje

La cosa es que consumo datos de una API de terceros, y quiero pintar los datos en un html... pero no muestra nada...

```
var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://api.elpais.com/ws/LoteriaNavidadPremiados?n=resumen",
"method": "GET",
"dataType": "jsonp",
"headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
}
```

}

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
document.getElementById("#numero1").innerHTML(response.numero1),
document.getElementById("#numero2").innerHTML(response.numero2),
document.getElementById("#numero3").innerHTML(response.numero3),
document.getElementById("#numero4").innerHTML(response.numero4),
document.getElementById("#numero5").innerHTML(response.numero5),
document.getElementById("#numero6").innerHTML(response.numero6),
document.getElementById("#numero7").innerHTML(response.numero7),
document.getElementById("#numero8").innerHTML(response.numero8),
document.getElementById("#numero9").innerHTML(response.numero9),
document.getElementById("#numero10").innerHTML(response.numero10),
document.getElementById("#numero11").innerHTML(response.numero11),
document.getElementById("#numero12").innerHTML(response.numero12),
document.getElementById("#numero13").innerHTML(response.numero13),
document.getElementById("#timestamp").innerHTML(response.timestamp),
document.getElementById("#status").innerHTML(response.status),
document.getElementById("#fraseSorteoPDF").innerHTML(response.fraseSorteoPDF),
document.getElementById("#fraseListaPDF").innerHTML(response.fraseListaPDF),
document.getElementById("#listaPDF").innerHTML(response.listaPDF),
document.getElementById("#urlAudio").innerHTML(response.urlAudio)
```

});

Y para el html lo intento llamar con id="xxx"

Muchas gracias!!!

---

Captura de lo que aparece en Sources
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Verificaste que te esté llegando la respuesta? verifica en la consola del navegador lo que ese console.log te está devolviendo.

Comment: Lo acabo de verificar... es cierto que en la consola no aparece nada, pero en sources si aparece el resultado :S

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfpub5hv50gprbg/screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: Añade una imagen de lo que dices al post, además, cambia cada .innerHTML(response.tunumerito) por .innerHTML = response.tunumerito

Comment: Al cambiar lo que me comentabas ya no aparece la api en Source. Alguna idea?

Comment: Las peticiones con `jsonp` por lo general necesitan un `callback`, para poder obtener la respuesta del servidor. ¿En la documentación de la API no te explican cómo se llama el callback o qué código Javascript hay que implementar para leer la respuesta?

Comment: Te comento... la petición jsonp la he añadido porque si no en la consola me aparecía un error de CORS (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource). Quizás el error esté aquí y pueda solventar esto de otro modo y no añadiendo una petición jsonp...

En lo referente a la documentación de la API son muy escuetos... https://servicios.elpais.com/sorteos/loteria-navidad/api/ solo comentan tres parámetros que se le pueden pasar... :S